# Add a UIView over the top of UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I currently use a UITableViewController (PFQueryTableViewController), I would like to display a UIView over the top of the TableView.

Ideally I'd like to do this in the storyboard, so I can easily add additional Labels/buttons to it. However, I can't seem to figure out how or if you can do it in storyboard. Is that right?

I have tried it programmatically. I first created the variable at the top:

`var filterLabelView:UIView = UIView()`

I then added the following in `ViewDidLoad` :

```
filterLabelView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height/2, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40)
filterLabelView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width  / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
filterLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(filterLabelView) // See below
```

I also tried:

```
self.view.insertSubview(filterLabelView, aboveSubview: tableView)
```

This creates the red UIView, but it seems to be embedded to the tableview, as when I scroll up and down, the View moves with it.

**What I want to create**

Ideally, I want the view to sit at the bottom of the screen, and **not** move when the user scrolls. An example screenshot of how I want it look is below:

[image]

I have read that the best way is to use a UIViewController with a UITableView inside it, but I'd rather not take that approach seeing how much my app is already built up.

Can anyone help me create this look? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to derive from `UIViewController` to get full layout control.

Then simply add a `UITableView` instance in Storyboard. Constrain it normally, edge-flush, top-flush, and have `customView.top` = `tableView.bottom`. Make a normal outlet to your controller.

You just need to remember to make your custom `UIViewController` adopt the usual dataSource and delegate protocols, as well as assigning itself as those roles to the properties of the `UITableView` on initialization (usually `viewDidLoad()`).

There's one more finesse related to clearing the selected cell when on `viewDidAppear()`, but there's nothing else special about a `UITableViewController` -- it's just a `UIViewController` with a built-in `tableView` property and automatically assigned delegates and a very inflexible layout.

ADDENDUM based on comment about how to get around this: It's sort of like asking if there is any way to make a screwdriver drive a nail into wood. Just use the right tool. The top-level `view` property of a `UITableViewController` is the `UITableView` itself. See below, a stock `UITableViewController` with nothing else, zero code, in layout debug mode.

This means the entire tree of views is embedded in a scrolled entity, so all subviews will scroll with it.

It really shouldn't be that big a deal to re-do this one VC in Storyboard. After all, your rendering code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and your dataSource and delegate generally, don't change at all.

ADDENDUM 2:

Not knowing Parse intimately, this may not be possible. (!! Thanks, Parse.) If Parse doesn't supply you with a separable `PFQueryTableView` that you can embed yourself, the following workaround may be possible, but you'll need to understand the Objective-C code:

https://www.parse.com/questions/pfquery-tableview-for-uiviewcontroller

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have read that actually. Is this the only way to achieve this? My app is quite heavily built up now, and would like to try avoid re building my main screen again. Do you think there is another way? thanks in advance

Comment: @Nick89 using a `UIViewController` is prob the best way to go, unless your `tableview` has only one section, then you could set `viewForHeaderInSection` and make it "sticky".

Comment: @kye Hi Kye, could you show me how to add that in, I've not added one before?

Comment: @BaseZen thanks for amending your answer again, would it still be possible for me to change over to a normal VC either though I'm set up using a PFQueryTableViewController?

Comment: @Nick89 you can simply add a `viewForHeaderInSection` to your tableview. I think `UITableView` by default sticks headers (header is shown while scrolling). Keep in mind this will not recreated your desired layout (screenshot shown), the best option is a `UIViewController` as stated in the answer above

Comment: @Nick89 Parse is more restrictive than I thought, take a look at Addendum 2